# How do I get 'onoff' working on a Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to make a 'Coocking-aid'. I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B with the official 7" touchscreen and an active piezo buzzer. The 'program' should run in Chromium (the RPi's webbrowser) and I write it in HTML, CSS and Javascript. I can do some tricks in Javascript but lack a lot of knowledge there. I try to sound the buzzer with Javascript, but so far without success.

The buzzer is connected between GPIO-pin 17 and Ground (connector-pins 11 and 9). When GPIO 17 is made high (+3V) the buzzer will sound.
I have tested this 'circuit' with a small Python program, which successfully turned the buzzer on:

```
1. from gpiozero import Buzzer
2. buzzer = Buzzer(17)
3. buzzer.on()
```

To do the same with Javascript I learned that I needed to install Node.js and its module 'onoff'.

From this web-post [1](https://thisdavej.com/beginners-guide-to-installing-node-js-on-a-raspberry-pi/) I learned how to install node.js, by typing the following commands in the terminal:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt install -y nodejs
```

I checked the installation by typing: "node -v". The response was: "v15.12.0"
I also checked the version of Node's package manager by typing: "npm -v". The response was: "7.7.5"

From this web-post [2](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_raspberrypi_gpio_intro.asp) I learned how to install "onoff" by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
npm install onoff
```

I checked the installation by typing: "node -v". The response was "v15.12.0"

In the RPi directory "/home/pi/node_modules/onoff/examples" is a file called: "blink-led.js"
which I used as an example to create (in the same directory) a file called: "test.js" with the following code:

```
'use strict';
const Gpio = require('../onoff').Gpio;  // Gpio class
const buzzer = new Gpio(17, 'out');     // Export GPIO17 as an output
buzzer.writeSync(17);                    // Make GPIO-pin 17 high
```

In the terminaI I moved to the same directory by typing:

```
cd /home/pi/node_modules/onoff/examples
```

and then executed "test.js" file by typing:

```
node test.js
```

Unfortunately the buzzer was not activated and a comprehensive error message was shown (see under).
I get the impression that the numbers are program line numbers and I had a look here and there, but I can't figure out what is wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated!.

The error message was:

```
/home/pi/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:121
        throw e;
        ^

Error: libnode.so.64: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at bindings (/home/pi/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
    at /home/pi/node_modules/epoll/epoll.js:7:31
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/epoll/epoll.js:15:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Comment: The documentation for the [`epoll` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/epoll) (which is used by `onoff`) suggests that the latest node version supported by it is 14 - worth a shot uninstalling node and downgrading to 14? By the way, try [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for managing node versions.

Comment: @cbr: npm was automatically installed with node by the scrip from web-post 1. My understanding of this post was that the script installs node in such a way that it could be upgraded in the standard Linux way. Wat is the advantage of nvm? I have little knowledge of Linux and am learning all the time. How do I uninstall node. How do I exchange npm by nvm?